# VBA to Combine Tabs (with similar names) from Different Excel Workbooks, each With Multiple Tabs

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 50 xlsx files in a folder that have three tabs: 1. Active, 2. Active Change, and 3. Suspended.  I want to combine all the tabs with names similar to "Suspended" into one workbook.  I keep getting syntax errors in the 7th line of code, "**For Sheets...**".  Any help rectifying this would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub GetSheets()
Path = "C:\Users\Tracy Anderson Dell\Dropbox\Memberships & Subs Tracking\MBO\Membership\59th Street\"
Filename = Dir(Path & ".xlsx")
strSheetName = "Suspended"
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
For Sheets(strSheetName).Select In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Next Sheet
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variables and create a workbook variable then just copy the sheet without the worksheet loop.

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\Users\Tracy Anderson Dell\Dropbox\Memberships & Subs Tracking\MBO\Membership\59th Street\"

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(path & ".xlsx")

    Dim strSheetName As String
    strSheetName = "Suspended"

    Do While fileName <> ""
        Dim wkb As Workbook
        Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=path & fileName, ReadOnly:=True)

        wbk.Worksheets(strsheename).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

        wkb.Close
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```